ipywidgets interactive with variable containers of widgets
For some interactive data analysis with Jupyter and ipywidgets, I generate a number of widgets depending on the data.
I.e. eventually I have a number of GridBoxes with Checkboxes, RangeSliders and ColorPickers which I layout in a Tab-Widget.
Now I tried to use
categories = ["A", "B", "C"] # retrieve from dataset
cbox = widgets.GridBox(children=[ widgets.Checkbox(value=True, description=v) for v in categories ])
rbox = widgets.GridBox(children=[ widgets.IntRangeSlider(value=[1,10], max=20, min=0, description=v) for v in categories ])


def analysis(variables, ranges):
    print("Hello. Currently I do nothing with the input!")

display(widgets.Tab(children=[cbox, rbox], titles=('Variables', 'Ranges')))
display(widgets.interactive_output(analysis, {"variables":cbox, "ranges":rbox}))

Which does not work:
AttributeError: 'GridBox' has no attribute 'value'

I also tried:
display(widgets.interactive_output(analysis, {"variables":cbox.children, "ranges":rbox.children}))

which also does not work.
Is it somehow possible to pass any type of container of some sort to my interactivized function, or do I need to ressort to kwargs? And if so, how would you do that efficiently?

I use ipywidget version 8.1.5

I think you were on the right track with trying display(widgets.interactive_output(analysis, {"variables":cbox.children, "ranges":rbox.children})). Your code works well with the variation display(widgets.interactive_output(analysis, {"variables":cbox.children[0], "ranges":rbox.children[0]})), but of course, only passes information about the first one of each in. The key thing is that it still wants a dictionary as the second argument, like in the documentation example for widgets.interactive().
You can still use a dictionary like in the documentation with a variable number of widgets being passed in, but you do essentially need to use kwargs. kwargs are really just a dictionary and you specify the handling when it goes into function with double asterisks. Since the interactive-ized function wants a dictionary, these are fully compatible and you just need the signal of the ** in the function parameter.
Here is an option for implementing this idea fleshed out to more of what I think you were after:
import ipywidgets as widgets
categories = ["A", "B", "C"] # retrieve from dataset
cbox = widgets.GridBox(children=[ widgets.Checkbox(value=True, description=v) for v in categories ])
rbox = widgets.GridBox(children=[ widgets.IntRangeSlider(value=[1,10], max=20, min=0, description=v) for v in categories ])


def analysis(**widget_dict):
    print("Hello. Currently I do nothing with the input!")
    variables = {}
    ranges = {}
    for k, v in widget_dict.items():
        if k.startswith('cbox'):
            variables[categories[int(k[4:])]] = v #slice of key leaves off 'cbox' and then use as integer to get relative category
        else:
            ranges[categories[int(k[4:])]] = v #slice of key leaves off 'rbox' and then use as integer to get relative category
    print("VARIABLES:")
    [print (f"  {category}: {value}") for category,value in variables.items()]
    print("RANGES:")
    [print (f"  {category}: {value}") for category,value in ranges.items()]

widget_dict = {}
for i, child in enumerate(cbox.children):
    widget_dict[f'cbox{i}'] = child
for i, child in enumerate(rbox.children):
    widget_dict[f'rbox{i}'] = child

display(widgets.Tab(children=[cbox, rbox], titles=('Variables', 'Ranges')))
display(widgets.interactive_output(analysis, widget_dict))


The answer of @Wayne is absolutly correct, however meanwhile I came up with a slightly different solution.
The essential idea is, that my function needs the additional **kwargs for the update-notification only, accessing the required information from another scope. So I add the **kwargs argument, but I don't use it inside the function body, so I don't have to restore any original structures from the dictionary.
To make things a bit cleaner I construct a closure for that.
def analyisis(a, b, c):
    # my original analysis-function
    print([ s.description for s in a.children if s.value ])

def closef(f, *args, **kwargs):
    cargs = args
    ckwargs = kwargs

    # I think this is different from functools.partial,
    # having **kwargs, that are completley ignored.
    def call(**kwargs):
        return f(*cargs, **ckwargs)
       
    return call

def kwargify(*args):
   # transforms all lists of controls into the required dict.
   # for brevity

# Display the Controls-Widgets in the Tabs
display(controls)
# Display the Output
display(widgets.interactive_output(closef(analysis, taba, tabb, tabc), kwargify(taba.children, tabb.children, tabc.children))

The upside of this method is, that I also have access to other metadata I might have stored in the control widgets, such as the description (as seen in the example analysis-function.
Usually only the values of the controls are passed. For me this is extremely helpful to create dynamically filters for my data.

I'm trying to understand this snippet. (Minor thing is the last line has a typo, I think? Missing a closing parentheses?) I'm trying to relate this to the original code you shared. You added an extra widgets.Tab() here that is tabc?

You may be right. I tried to generify my "production"-code in the answer-window, without readapting it to the initial example. After work, I'll fix this.
